How to Read All Class Information from Current Project in an External Project
I'm currently developing a server framework (referred to as A) in Java.
I want to read all the class information of the web application server (referred to as B) using the framework package.
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
try {
    Enumeration<URL> resources = classLoader.getResources("");
    while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
        URL resource = resources.nextElement();
        retrieveFile(new File(resource.getFile()), "");
        if (this.rootPackageName != null) return;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new ComponentScanNotFoundException();
}

I'm trying to analyze the above code and create a singleton instance.
It works fine in IDEs like IntelliJ, but when I create an executable JAR file and try to run it, the return value of resources.hasMoreElements() is false.
When running in IntelliJ, if I check the classpath of project A, I can see all the package information that project B depends on, but after building the JAR, when I run it with the java -jar command, only project B information is visible. Is this an error caused by incorrect classpath configuration? If not, could you please let me know what the problem is? Thank you.

File only works with actuals files on a filesystem not with files inside an archive like a jar or zip. So you need to find a way without using File but rather only an InputStream.
